# Why does the Mahabharata mention Lakshmi as the consort of Dharma?

Tags: mahabharata, lakshmi

We all know that Lakshmi Devi is the consort of Lord Vishnu.

But, at one place the MahAbhArata mentions Lakshmi as the consort of Dharma.

> NAmato dharma patnyastAh kirtyamAnA nivodh me |
>
> Kirti **lakshmi** dhritirmedhA pushti shraddhA kriyA tathA ||
>
> BuddhirlajjA matishchaiva **patnau dharmasya ta dasha** |
>
> **MahAbhArata Adi Parva 18-35**

The ten daughters of Daksha who are all wedded to Dharma are mentioned here as- Kirti, Lakshmi, Dhriti, MedhA, Pushti, SraddhA, KriA, Buddhi, LajjA and Mati.

Here Lakshmi is mentioned as Daksha's daughter and Dharma's wife. Why is it so?

Is this Lakshmi the same as the consort of Lord Vishnu or is she someone else? Can someone clarify?

Comment: Yes , In Bhagvat purana names of those 10 daughters are different.Here in gita press edition only word  Dharma is mentioned .But Prabhupada is saying that dharma is Yamaraja. Here -https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/6/4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lakshmi, the daughter of Bhrigu, is married to Lord Vishnu. And Lakshmi, the daughter of Daksha, is married to Dharma.  The same section conveys that Lakshmi is the daughter of Bhrigu is at lotus feet. Mahabharata is like a jigsaw puzzle. Each incidence in isolation is confusing. Together when put conveys the real meaning. [SECTION LXVI ADI PARVA text here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01067.htm)

Comment: Where does it say in the link that Lakshmi was Bhrigu's daughter? See Bibek Debroy's [translation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28cIe.jpg). It says, Brahma (not Bhrigu) had two other sons Dhata and Vidhata and a daughter named Lakshmi.